# The dimension of $W_1\cap W_2$ is at most $5.$ Yes/No

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be the vector space of all polynomials in one variable of degree at most $10$ with real coefficients. Let $W_1$ be the subspace of $V$ consisting of polynomials of degree at most $5$ and let $W_2$ be the subspace of $V$ consisting of polynomials such that the sum of their coefficients is $0.$ Let $W$ be the smallest subspace of $V$ containing both $W_1$ and $W_2$. Which of the following statements are true?

$1.$ The dimension of $W$ is at most $10.$

$2. W = V.$

$3. W_1 \subset W_2.$

$4.$ The dimension of $W_1\cap W_2$ is at most $5.$

**My attempt**: I think option $3$ is correct

$W_1=\{ p(x) \in V | \deg(p(x)) \le 5 \}\implies \dim(W_1)=6$

$ W_2 =\{ p(x) \in V | a_0+a_1+a_2+.....+a_{10}=0\}\implies \dim W_2=9$

$\dim V=\dim W_1 + \dim W_2 - \dim(W_1\cap W_2)=6+9- \dim(W_1\cap W_2)$

Therefore $\dim(W_1\cap W_2)=15-11=4$

Comment: Options 1 and 3 are wrong, options 2 is correct, $\dim W_2=10$, and $\dim(W_1\cap W_2)=5$.

Comment: okay @AnneBauval but $\dim W_1 \neq \dim W_2$ . Could you please explain why option 2 is correct?

Comment: $\dim W_1 =6$ and $\dim W_2= 10$ @AnneBauval

Comment: $dim W= \dim W_1 \cap W_2$ @AnneBauval

Comment: Indeed. These dimensions for $W_1$ and $W_2$ agree with what I said. And option 2 is correct because $W=W_1+W_2$ and $W_2$ is a hyperplane and $W_1\not\subset W_2$. And no, $\dim W=11\ne\dim(W_1\cap W_2)=5$.

Comment: But $\dim (W) = 10+6=16 \neq dim V=11$ @AnneBauval

Comment: No, $\dim W\ne10+6$, since $W=V$, as explained in my previous comment.

Comment: okay @AnneBauval I'm confused again $\dim V=11 \neq \dim W=10$

Comment: Again: $W=V$ and $\dim W=\dim V=11$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you, I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments of Anne Bauval help me to answer. Thanks!

We will show that $V=W_1+W_2$.

Note that
$$W_1=\left\{\left.\sum_{n=0}^5a_nx^n\right\vert a_0,\ldots,a_5\in\Bbb R\right\};\\
W_2=\left\{\left.\sum_{n=1}^{10}b_n(x^n-1)\right\vert b_1,\ldots,b_{10}\in\Bbb R\right\}.$$

Note that every vector $\sum_{n=0}^{10}c_nx^n\in V$ can be written as
$$\sum_{n=0}^{10}c_nx^n=\sum_{n=0}^{10}c_n+\sum_{n=1}^{10}c_n(x^n-1),$$
where
$$\sum_{n=0}^{10}c_n\in W_1 \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ \sum_{n=1}^{10}c_n(x^n-1)\in W_2.$$
Therefore, $V=W_1+W_2$.

Now, we can answer:

$1.$ **False**. Because $\dim W=11$. Indeed, $W=W_1+W_2$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing both $W_1$ and $W_2$ and we have proved that $V=W_1+W_2$, it follows that $W=V$.

$2.$ **True**.

$3.$ **False**. Because $x^5\in W_1$, but $x^5\notin W_2$.

$4.$ **True**. Because $\dim(W_1\cap W_2)=5$. Indeed, $\dim(W_1+W_2)=\dim(V)=11$, $\dim(W_1)=6$, and $\dim(W_2)=10$, it follows that
$$\dim(W_1+W_2)=\dim(W_1)+\dim(W_2)-\dim(W_1\cap W_2)\implies\dim(W_1\cap W_2)=5.$$

Answer (score 2):

Option 3 is false, i.e. $W_1\not\subset W_2$: for instance, $1\in W_1\setminus W_2.$

Since moreover $W_2$ is a hyperplane in $V$, the subspace $W=W_1+W_2$ is therefore equal to the whole space $V$, i.e. option 2 is true.

As a consequence, $\dim W=\dim V=11$ hence option 1 is false.

Finally, option 4 is true: since $W_1\cap W_2$ is a hyperplane in $W_1$, its dimension equals $(\dim W_1)-1=5$.